# Assembley procedure in pascal code?

Tags: assembly, pascal

I was reading pascal source code when i met this procedure:

```
  procedure Copier_Bytewise (const source, target; const Count: word);
  (* $ IFDEF VirtualPascal *)
  assembler; (* $ Uses ESI, EDI, ECX *) (* $ Frame-*)
  asm
    mov esi, source
    mov edi, target
    mov ecx, Count
    cld
    rep movsb
  end;
  (* $ ELSE *)
  .
  (* $ ENDIF *)
```

This procedure is called wit these arguments :

```
Copier_Bytewise (Unpacked [WritePosition-Backwards], Unpacked [WritePosition], length);
```

So, What exactly is being copied?!

Comment: movsb moves a byte from the source pointer to destination (esi to edi, what their contents point at) and increments each.  the rep means repeat repeat this instruction (movsb) ecx number of times.  this is all documented in the x86 instruction set manuals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source address is memory address of: `Unpacked [WritePosition-Backwards]`

The destination address is memory address of: `Unpacked [WritePosition]`

The copied content in bytes is: `length`

Comment: So, If every element is one byte, this procedure copies length number of elements from the array starting at "WritePosition-Backwards" to offset "WritePosition" ?

Comment: Exactly. Element size is byte because `movsb` instruction is in use. The address of source/destination is memory address of `Unpacked [xxx]` array member. (We don't know the type of `Unpacked` array.)

Comment: unpacked sounds more like a modifier to signify that the address xxx might not be aligned